# How to access a public function outside custom component in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an application width a `mx:ViewStack` component with differents view components under each `s:NavigatorContent` as it follows.

```
<mx:ViewStack id="vsOne" resizeToContent="true">
    <s:NavigatorContent label="First">
        <package:MyFirstComponent id="myFirstComponent"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
    <s:NavigatorContent label="Second">
        <package:MySecondComponent id="mySecondComponent"/>
    </s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
```

And this is `package.MyFirstComponent`'s important part..

```
<s:Button label="Next" click="somethingToGoForward()"/>
```

What I've tried:

1. Calling `somethingToGoForward()` in the view component and triyng to access to a `parent` `vsOne`: Don't work.
2. Calling `parent.somethingToGoForward()` (when this method is in the same mxml as the `ViewStack`): Don't work

How can I change my `ViewStack`'s `selectedIndex` from anywhere outside the mxml file containing it?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2013/2/1/How-does-one-Flex-Component-talk-to-another-Flex-Component

Comment: Events.. of course.. thanks.. Great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example using simple events:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"     initialize="application1_initializeHandler(event)"
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"  xmlns:local="*">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            viewStack.selectedChild=one;

        }

        protected function one_changeViewHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            viewStack.selectedChild=two;
        }

        protected function two_changeViewHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            viewStack.selectedChild=one;

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:ViewStack id="viewStack" >
    <local:ccomp id="one" changeView="one_changeViewHandler(event)" text="LAbel ONE">

    </local:ccomp>
    <local:ccomp id="two" changeView="two_changeViewHandler(event)" text="LAbel TWO" >

    </local:ccomp>
</mx:ViewStack>
</s:Application>
```

ccomp is a custom component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:HBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">
<fx:Metadata>
    [Event(name="changeView", type="mx.events.FlexEvent")]  
</fx:Metadata>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        private var _text:String;

        public function get text():String
        {
            return _text;
        }
        [Bindable]
        public function set text(value:String):void
        {
            _text = value;
        }

        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            this.dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent("changeView",true));               
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
</fx:Declarations>
    <s:Button label="Change" click="button1_clickHandler(event)">
    </s:Button>
    <s:Label fontSize="24" text="{text}">
    </s:Label>
   </mx:HBox>
```

Davide